# Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the array type String[]

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

I'm doing a function that counts digits in a string:

```
int countOccurences(String str) {

    // split the string by spaces in a
    String a[] = str.split(" ");

    // search for pattern in a
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        char b = a.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(b))
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

The error is:

```
Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the array type String[]"
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to invoke the [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) method on a `String[]`. `String[]` does not have such a method, but `String` does. What I believe you wanted to do is:

```
char b = a[i].charAt(i);
```

This will get the `char` at position `i` in the `String` at position `i` from your `String` array

Answer (score 2):

`a` is `String[]`, and it does not have method `charAt`. `String` does.

Comment: now i get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char"

Answer (score 1):

Besides other answers here, these is one more point. For your particular task the string do not need to be splitted. You can count number of digits in this way

```
String str = "some st2ring5 wit43h dig1its";

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    char b = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(b)) count++;
}

return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char b = a[i].charAt(i); // This is faulty.

/* It won't help because when your loop runs the first time it checks
   the first letter of the first string and when it runs the second time, 
   it checks the second letter of the second string of the array. */
```

**You don't need to convert the string to char[] only to check for digits in it.**
You can check it using the string itself.
**Try this:**

```
public int numOfDigits(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char b = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(b))
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String str = "hello1 world";
        String a[] = str.split(" ");

        // search for pattern in a
        int count = 0;
        char b ;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j< a[i].length() ; j++){
                b = a[i].charAt(j);
                if (Character.isDigit(b)){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
```

output : 1